# How to accept legacy .html requests for .cshtml pages in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a situation where I rewrite old site and need old .html urls to be accessible in the new project.

so before I had this:

```
domain.com/goodpage.html
```

with asp core now I have

```
domain.com/goodpage
```

but I need all the old domain.com/goodpage.html to redirect to

```
domain.com/goodpage
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Are you using IIS? You can use IIS redirects for this.

Comment: Actually was thinking to host it as server-less AWS Lambdas.

Comment: Perhaps you can create some custom routes in the MVC application then. Or, google whether redirection can be done with AWS Lambdas. e.g. this article was first on google https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/redirection-in-a-serverless-api-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/, there are others

Comment: Are you trying to redirect requests to the old URL to the new site? Or do you want your new site to handle requests in the old URL format, i.e. domain.com/xxx.html?

Comment: Given your example `domain.com/goodpage`, in your new site using ASP.NET CORE, is `goodpage` the name of the controller and the default action, which is `Index`, is to handle that request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("legacy", "{controller=Home}.html/{action=Index}");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I have no controllers and had to use razor routing: .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Index", "Index.html");